# How to disable an option from select laravel blade template

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade, html-select

I'm passing this array to a blade view:

```
$data['publish'] = [
    null => '- Select Ad Type -',
    1    => 'Featured Ad',
    2    => 'Normal Ad'
];
```

Within the view I'm creating a select input like this:

```
{{ Form::select('publish', $publish, null, array('class'=>'span10 m-wrap')) }}
```

How can I disable one option, for example `Featured Ad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't using the `Form::select` helper because the options use the `'value' => 'name'` format for each array item, so there's no way to specify the additional `disabled` attribute. You just have to build the select manually using a `@foreach` loop and add the disabled attribute using a condition:

```
<select name="publish" class="span10 m-wrap">
    @foreach ($publish as $value => $name)
        <option value="{{ $value }}"
            @if ($name == 'Featured Ad')
                disabled
            @endif
        >
            {{ $name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

As an alternative you could create your custom [`Form::macro`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros) that uses some other parameters that allows disabling individual options, but it seem too much of a hassle unless you need to use this in a lot of places.